# Nginx config for svelte SPA, Adapter-Static

Tags: nginx, server, sveltekit

please refer to this [link for information on spa's with respect to sveltekit](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/single-page-apps)

here is my nginx config:

```
server {
    root /var/www/example-site-name/build
    server_name example.com
    index home.html
}
```

this is my .htaccess file

[image]

what should my config be based on these build files?

[image]

i get this when i just visit example.com/

[image]

[image]

when i go to example.com/home I get 403.

The routes should be (based on the development environment)

https://example.com/home (home.html/aka index.html)

https://example.com/home/contact (home/contact.html)

https://example.com/home/about (home/about.html)

https://example.com/admin (admin.html/)